# PHP Session works fine under one directory, but the same code fails in a different directory

Tags: php, authentication, session, timeout

I have the below code that works fine under /t/cgi-bin/test1.php, but the same code fails under /p/cgi-bin/test1.php. Every time I run under /p/cgi-bin..., it takes me to test_log1.html right away. It is not waiting for 15 minutes before it times out to test_log1.html. Any help is appreciated.

```
<?php
      session_start();
      if(isset($_SESSION["test"]))
      {
                if((time() - $_SESSION['last_login_timestamp']) > 900)
           {
                header("location:../test_log1.html");
           }
           else
           {
                $_SESSION['last_login_timestamp'] = time();
           }
      }
      else
      {
           header('location:../test_log2.html');
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with the code. The file had to be recreated. It is working now. This post can be closed.

Comment: I dont believe it works as you intend.  To test, clear the browser cache.  If you are using Firefox or Brave use Ctrl + Shift + Del,  And then retry.

Comment: Agree, recreation of file doesn't make sense to me imho.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues.

### **One**

Perhaps because by default there is only one session per browser.  It's not per tab, or per url.

So, once you have run, the session already has the **last_login_timestamp**. It then uses the same value for the second session.

1. If you want them to be different  then you have to use different **session ids** for the two paths.
2. Another way is to **clear/reset** the session at the start of the file.
3. Yet another is to use a different test variable such as **test1** and **test2**.

### **Two**

**test** is never getting set, and the value of **last_login_timestamp** is null.  I am assuming that you are setting test elsewhere.  So, for testing, here is the updated code.  The **??** operator ensures that the value goes to time when it is null

```php
<?php
      session_start();

      if(isset($_SESSION["test"]))
      {
           $last = $_SESSION['last_login_timestamp'] ?? time();
           if((time() - $last) > 900)
           {
                header("location:../test_log1.html");
           }
           else
           {
                echo 'Has not timed out';
           }
      }
      else
      {
          $_SESSION["test"] = 'xx';
          header('location:../test_log2.html');
    }
?>
```

If you want three independent sessions then you have to use different session_ids or just different variables.  So use **test_p** and **last_login_timestamp_p** for directory p, etc.

### **Three**

PHP is a server side language. When run, nothing is sent to the browser, except the redirect, or echo from this code above.

Once the session variable is set, and 15 mins later you run the code, it will time out in both places.  This will keep happening from then on, until the session variable is cleared.

However, it can not time out on the browser and go to a different page by itself, after 15 mins.  For that you need to use javascript.

Comment: what is the command to clear/reset the session at the start of the file?

Comment: session_reset.  By the way, if it works for you then the process is to tick the answer

Comment: Information here  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sessions.htm

Comment: Added the session_reset under the session_start, but it did not work. I also, gave different names to the session, still the same issue.

Comment: I have recreated the file from /t/ to /p/ and it is working now.

Comment: Great, the protocol is to tick and vote for the answer it helped you.

Comment: None of the answers helped. Can I vote for the effort?

Comment: I did vote, but it says it cannot be recorded as I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: I have updated my answer with all the flaws in the code.  I had assumed that there was other code fiddling with the session variable.  You should set breakpoints (or use echo statements) at various places to convince yourself as to what is happening.

Comment: The above updated code from you works, except it is not timing out after the specified seconds.

Comment: As mentioned in point 3.  It cant run on the browser.  If you run the same page after 15min, it will time out.  And thats all this code can do.  Its all on the server side.  If you are expecting the browser page to time itself out, it has to be done in javascript.

Comment: I am trying to create a login under another folder /m and the same issue happens. I used your code and also, set session_reset(). The first login works fine and times out after 15 minutes as intended, but for logins thereafter, it will come to test_log1.html right away. Why? What is wrong?

Comment: For what you are trying to do, the best thing is to use different names.  I updated the answer above  Use test_p, test_m etc.

Comment: I changed the session names before my last comment, still same issue. That is why I am trying to figure out what is causing the issue. If I do echo on the session name, it shows up fine. The failure happens on the time out calculation. It recognizes right away that it is more than 15 minutes and goes to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
header('Location: '../test_log2.html');
```

Comment: this did not work. I have recreated the file from /t/ to /p/ and it is working now.